# How to implement Depth-first search through a tree of objects?

Tags: objective-c, recursion, iteration, depth-first-search

Looking for some code examples with explanation. Wikipedia is too abstract on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the Wikipedia sources. Here's what I found for you:

http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Graph/Undirected/Depth-first_search

It gives example and some code sample. Pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Get Complete Implementation of DFS in Java using Tree here http://c-madeeasy.blogspot.com/2011/08/dfsdepth-first-search-program-in-java.html